# how to change the value of dictionary using linq based on key?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary which is of type,

```
  Dictionary<string, string> newdictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  newdictionary.Add("12345", "chip1");
  newdictionary.Add("23456", "chip2");
```

Now i have a List which is of type

```
   internal class CustomSerial
    {
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public decimal ecoID { get; set; }
    } 
   var customList = new List<CustomSerial>();
   CustomSerial custObj1= new CustomSerial();
   custObj1.ecoID =1;
   custObj1.SerialNo = "12345";
   customList.Add(custObj1);
   CustomSerial custObj2 = new CustomSerial();
   custObj2.ecoID = 2;
   custObj2.SerialNo = "23456";
   customList.Add(custObj2);
```

Now i need to update the Initial dictionary by Filtering the Keys with ther SerialNumber and Replacing the values with the ecoID.

When i try this, it gives

```
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> each in newdictionary)
  {                       
    each.Value = customList.Where(t => t.SerialNo == each.Key).Select(t => t.ecoID).ToString();
  }
```

System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: What is `serials` ? Apart from that `LIN(Q)` is a tool to query not to update.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes newdictionary

Comment: foreach is used to retrive the data from collection you know that ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes i know that, but tried to replace after obtaining keys that too dint work, omiting that, is there any way to check for keys and update values?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Your `ToString()` on your last line of code is unlikely to be doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LIN(Q)` is a tool to query something not to update it. 
However, you can first query what you need to update. For example:

```
var toUpdate = customList
   .Where(c => newdictionary.ContainsKey(c.SerialNo))
   .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c.SerialNo, c.ecoID.ToString()));
foreach(var kv in toUpdate)
    newdictionary[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
```

By the way, you get the "KeyValuePair.Value' cannot be assigned to it is read only" exception because a`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a `struct` which cannot be modified.

Comment: is toUpdate is a dictionary?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: it's an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Comment: Thanks! will mark it as an answer after testing it :)

Comment: Instead of updating it's adding a new key and value

Comment: @Sajeetharan: no, i'm first taking only key-values which are already in the dictionary: `...Where(c => newdictionary.ContainsKey(c.SerialNo))`

Comment: is it possible for you to tell how can i update the Serialno with the ecoId Having chipids in values

Comment: @Sajeetharan: i don't understand the question. Do you want to update the key of the dictionary? That's not possible, you need to create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have the simplest in this form: though I don't see why you are assigning the same value but the method applies regardless

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "12345", "chip1" }, { "23456", "chip2" } };
                var customList = new List<CustomSerial>() { new CustomSerial() { ecoID = 1, SerialNo = "12345" }, new CustomSerial() { ecoID = 2, SerialNo = "23456" } };

                dictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
                {
                    dictionary[key] = customList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SerialNo == key).SerialNo;
                });
```