# Find and remove elements from List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I'm currently working on a C# 4.7.2 application. I'm about to write an extension method for a custom type and I'm struggling with my LINQ query unfortunately.

I need filter a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to find the elements of `Dictionary<string, object>` in the list with a certain key and remove it from my list. Furthermore, a list entry can be null.

A list entry (dictionary) can look like this, there can be several elements with value key A, i need to remove all actually:

```
Key    |  Value
"MyId" : "A",
"Width" : 100,
"Length" : 50
```

Very simple structure. The tricky thing is to find the dictionary elements in the list. My extension method looks like that:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> RemoveItem(this List<Dictionary<string, object> items, string value)
{
    var itemToRemove = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey("MyId")).Values.Contains(value);

    items.Remove(itemToRemove);

    return items;
}
```

Unfortunately this LINQ query does not work correctly.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: *Unfortunately this LINQ query does not work correctly.* What is happening with it?

Comment: "Does not work" has never been a suiteable problem description on a programming forum. Please tell us what exactly is happening or not happening.

Comment: Why you need the value?

Comment: Hi sorry, actually I need to remove all dictionary items from the list, that have the key MyId and it's value A, let's say...

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549702/4329813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all with a key and a value? You don't even need LINQ:

```
public static int RemoveItems(this List<Dictionary<string, object>> dictionaryList, string value)
{
    int removed = dictionaryList
        .RemoveAll(dict => dict.TryGetValue("MyId", out object val) && value.Equals(val));
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this helpful response! i added a null checker and it works very well!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method `RemoveAll` of the list. Then you give in a predicate that checks the dictionary (which is a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`):

```
items.RemoveAll(dict => dict.Any(kv => kv.Key == "MyId" && ( kv.Value as string ) == "A"));
```

Or as suggested by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter):

```
items.RemoveAll(dict => dict.TryGetValue("MyId", out object value) && (value as string) == "A");
```

Comment: I would not enumerate the dictionary to find keys, use `TryGetValue`

Comment: Depends on the size of the dictionary, but fair enough

Comment: well, if you use a dictionary then mostly because retrieving a value by using its key is very fast(`O(1)`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter better? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like:

```
itemsToRemove = items.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("MyId") && x["MyId"].ToString() == value);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you seem to want the first dictionary containing the key with the value from the parameter `value`. That would be `items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey(value))`

What you are doing is getting dictionary containing one predefined key `"myId"` and then going through the objects inside the dictionary and comparing their values with your `value` parameter, which is not what you described you want.

If you expect more dictionaries to contain the given key,and you want to remove all of them, you should use `list.RemoveAll(dict => dict.ContainsKey(value))`

Comment: The value should also match

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> RemoveItem(this List<Dictionary<string, object>> items, string value, string key)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if(item.ContainsKey(key) && item[key] == value)
        {
            item.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

This gonna work just fine.